# Initialising accounting groups

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

This deeply nested set of callbacks is very unreadable and I'm looking for ways to improve it:

```
seedGroups('Branch/Divisions', null, null, null, null, true, true, true, false, true, function(err, result) {
    seedGroups('Capital Account', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err2, result2) {
        seedGroups('Current Assets', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err3, result3) {
            seedGroups('Current Liabilities', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, false, false, false, false, function(err4, result4) {
                seedGroups('Direct Expenses', null, null, 'Trading Account', 'Expenses', true, false, false, false, false, function(err5, result5) {
                    seedGroups('Direct Incomes', null, null, 'Trading Account', 'Incomes', true, false, false, false, false, function(err6, result6) {
                        seedGroups('Fixed Assets', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err7, result7) {
                            seedGroups('Indirect Expenses', null, null, 'Profit & Loss A/c', 'Expenses', true, false, false, false, false, function(err8, result8) {
                                seedGroups('Indirect Incomes', null, null, 'Profit & Loss A/c', 'Incomes', true, false, false, false, false, function(err9, result9) {
                                    seedGroups('Investments', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err10, result10) {
                                        seedGroups('Loans (Liability)', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, false, true, function(err11, result11) {
                                            seedGroups('Misc. Expenses (Asset)', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err12, result12) {
                                                seedGroups('Purchase Accounts', null, null, 'Trading Account', 'Expenses', true, false, false, false, false, function(err13, result13) {
                                                    seedGroups('Sales Accounts', null, null, 'Trading Account', 'Incomes', true, false, false, false, false, function(err14, result14) {
                                                        seedGroups('Suspense Account', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, false, false, false, false, function(err15, result15) {
                                                            seedGroups('Bank Accounts', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, true, false, function(err16, result16) {
                                                                seedGroups('Bank OD A/c', 'Bank OCC A/c', 'Loans (Liability)', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, true, false, function(err17, result17) {
                                                                    seedGroups('Cash-in-Hand', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err18, result18) {
                                                                        seedGroups('Deposits (Asset)', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err19, result19) {
                                                                            seedGroups('Duties & Taxes', null, 'Current Liabilities', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, false, false, false, false, function(err20, result20) {
                                                                                seedGroups('Loans & Advances (Asset)', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err21, result21) {
                                                                                    seedGroups('Provisions', null, 'Current Liabilities', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, false, false, false, false, function(err22, result22) {
                                                                                        seedGroups('Reserves & Surplus', 'Retained Earnings', 'Capital Account', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err23, result23) {
                                                                                            seedGroups('Secured Loans', null, 'Loans (Liability)', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, false, true, function(err24, result24) {
                                                                                                seedGroups('Stock-in-Hand', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err25, result25) {
                                                                                                    seedGroups('Sundry Creditors', null, 'Current Liabilities', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, false, true, function(err26, result26) {
                                                                                                        seedGroups('Sundry Debtors', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err27, result27) {
                                                                                                            seedGroups('Unsecured Loans', null, 'Loans (Liability)', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, false, true, function(err28, result28) {
                                                                                                                console.log('Groups Saved!');
                                                                                                            });
                                                                                                        });
                                                                                                    });
                                                                                                });
                                                                                            });
                                                                                        });
                                                                                    });
                                                                                });
                                                                            });
                                                                        });
                                                                    });
                                                                });
                                                            });
                                                        });
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Update:**

```
function seedGroups(groupName, alias, parentName, effectName, natureName, isSystemGroup, mailing, contact, bank, tax, callback) {
    Effect.find({ name: effectName || '' })
        .exec(function(err, effect) {
            if(err) { console.log(err); }
            else {
                Nature.find({ name: natureName || '' })
                        .exec(function(err2, nature) {
                            if(err2) { console.log(err2); }
                            else {
                                Group.find({ name: parentName || '' })
                                    .exec(function(err3, parent) {
                                        if(err3) { console.log(err3); }
                                        else {
                                            var group = new Group({
                                                name: groupName,
                                                alias: alias || undefined,
                                                parent: parent != null ? parent[0] : undefined,
                                                effect: effect != null ? effect[0] : undefined,
                                                nature: nature != null ? nature[0] : undefined,
                                                isSystemGroup: isSystemGroup || false,
                                                details: {
                                                    mailing: mailing || false,
                                                    contact: contact || false,
                                                    bank: bank || false,
                                                    tax: tax || false
                                                }
                                            });
                                            group.save(function(err4, result){
                                                if(err4) {console.log(err4);}
                                                else { callback(); }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you reverse the order of the methods? Instead of:

```
seedGroups('Branch/Divisions', null, null, null, null, true, true, true, false, true, function(err, result) {
    seedGroups('Capital Account', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err2, result2) {
        seedGroups('Current Assets', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err3, result3) {
          console.log('Groups Saved');
       });
    });
});
```

Do:

```
function seedBranchesAndDivisions() {
    seedGroups('Branch/Divisions', null, null, null, null,
               true, true, true, false, true, 
               seedCapitalAccount);
}
function seedCapitalAccount(error, result) {
    seedGroups('Capital Account', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', 
               true, true, true, false, true, 
               seedCurrentAssets;
}
function seedCurrentAssets(error, result) {
    seedGroups('Current Assets', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', 
               true, false, false, false, false, 
               logComplete);
}
function logComplete(error, result) {
    console.log('Groups Saved');
}

seedBranchesAndDivisions();
```

Or for a more over-engineered solution:

```
let groups = [
    ['Branch/Divisions', null, null, null,            null,      true, true,  true,  false, true ],
    ['Capital Account',  null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets',  true, true,  true,  false, true ],
    ['Current Assets',   null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets',  true, false, false, false, false],
];

let callback = function(e,r) { console.log('Groups Saved'); };

groups[ groups.length-1 ].push(callback);
for (let i = groups.length-1; i>= 0; i--) {
  let group = groups[i];
  group.push( callback );
  callback = function(e,r) { seedGroups.apply(this, group); }
}
callback();
```

Comment: I like your over-engineered solution. That works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time and hard work.

Comment: This line was actually redundant `groups[ groups.length-1 ].push(callback);`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the thing... you're not really doing callbacks at all. You're ignoring the error values, and the result values, so you may as well have the code:

```
seedGroups('Branch/Divisions', null, null, null, null, true, true, true, false, true, function(err, result) {});
seedGroups('Capital Account', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err2, result2) {});
seedGroups('Current Assets', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err3, result3) {});
seedGroups('Current Liabilities', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, false, false, false, false, function(err4, result4) {});
seedGroups('Direct Expenses', null, null, 'Trading Account', 'Expenses', true, false, false, false, false, function(err5, result5) {});
seedGroups('Direct Incomes', null, null, 'Trading Account', 'Incomes', true, false, false, false, false, function(err6, result6) {});
seedGroups('Fixed Assets', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err7, result7) {});
seedGroups('Indirect Expenses', null, null, 'Profit & Loss A/c', 'Expenses', true, false, false, false, false, function(err8, result8) {});
seedGroups('Indirect Incomes', null, null, 'Profit & Loss A/c', 'Incomes', true, false, false, false, false, function(err9, result9) {});
seedGroups('Investments', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err10, result10) {});
seedGroups('Loans (Liability)', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, false, true, function(err11, result11) {});
seedGroups('Misc. Expenses (Asset)', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err12, result12) {});
seedGroups('Purchase Accounts', null, null, 'Trading Account', 'Expenses', true, false, false, false, false, function(err13, result13) {});
seedGroups('Sales Accounts', null, null, 'Trading Account', 'Incomes', true, false, false, false, false, function(err14, result14) {});
seedGroups('Suspense Account', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, false, false, false, false, function(err15, result15) {});
seedGroups('Bank Accounts', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, true, false, function(err16, result16) {});
seedGroups('Bank OD A/c', 'Bank OCC A/c', 'Loans (Liability)', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, true, false, function(err17, result17) {});
seedGroups('Cash-in-Hand', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err18, result18) {});
seedGroups('Deposits (Asset)', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err19, result19) {});
seedGroups('Duties & Taxes', null, 'Current Liabilities', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, false, false, false, false, function(err20, result20) {});
seedGroups('Loans & Advances (Asset)', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err21, result21) {});
seedGroups('Provisions', null, 'Current Liabilities', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, false, false, false, false, function(err22, result22) {});
seedGroups('Reserves & Surplus', 'Retained Earnings', 'Capital Account', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err23, result23) {});
seedGroups('Secured Loans', null, 'Loans (Liability)', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, false, true, function(err24, result24) {});
seedGroups('Stock-in-Hand', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false, function(err25, result25) {});
seedGroups('Sundry Creditors', null, 'Current Liabilities', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, false, true, function(err26, result26) {});
seedGroups('Sundry Debtors', null, 'Current Assets', 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true, function(err27, result27) {});
seedGroups('Unsecured Loans', null, 'Loans (Liability)', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, false, true, function(err28, result28) {});
console.log('Groups Saved!');
```

Having said that, if you want a better solution and still handle the errors properly, etc, you should consider using a Promise. You can make your `seedGroup` function adaptable by testing whether a callback function is provided, and if it is, you call the callback, if it's not provided, you return a Promise. Your code could then look like:

```
seedGroups('Branch/Divisions', null, null, null, null, true, true, true, false, true)
    .then(() =>  seedGroups('Capital Account', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, true, true, false, true))
    .then(() => seedGroups('Current Assets', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Assets', true, false, false, false, false))
    .then(() => seedGroups('Current Liabilities', null, null, 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, false, false, false, false))
    .then(........)
    .then(() => seedGroups('Unsecured Loans', null, 'Loans (Liability)', 'Balance Sheet', 'Liabilities', true, true, true, false, true))
    .then(() => console.log('Groups Saved!'))
    .catch(err => .... some error handling ...);
```

Comment: I have tried the code you suggested before. But I have problems with that. There is a specific reason behind using callback system. What I am doing here is : Let's say I am not using callback system as you said, then when I save the groups they are not saved in order I provided. Order here is important because one group is parent of another. So, first parent group should be saved and then it should be referenced in another group. For more details on seedGroups function you can see the update part of the question.

Comment: I don't see anything in there that prevents you changing the callback to a promise.